# Enable the "dashed line" around buttons after hitting tab?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if any of you guys know how to show that "dashed line" that appears whenever you hit tab to buttons? I don't know which css code is hiding that. Is is a:active? (assuming this is a css thing?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input:focus {
   border: 1px dashed #000;
   outline: none; }
```

It's the Focus selector that controls it.

Answer (score 0):

The outline CSS property controls the dotted line that you see around input fields when they have focus.  Setting the outline to 0 will remove that dotted line.

```
outline: 0;
```

For more information, see the following article:

http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Comment: Might be because outline:0; will do nothing if you don't specify the :Focus selector for input items (like a button). Outline: 0; will only work, generally, for anchor tags.

Comment: @Scott I didn't specify a selector at all.  That doesn't mean the answer is wrong.  I don't know who downvoted, but it'd be much more constructor to include a comment suggesting that the `:focus` pseudo-selector be used.